# How can I resolve my issue with datatable 'mData of undefined' c#

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable

I add datatable to my gridview but when I do that I have this error :

> Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined

I don't understand why I have this error because :

- I have the same number of th and td
- I select the good id

Someone have a solution for me ?

**aspx.cs**

```
protected void DD_List_Date_Select_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GV.DataSourceID = DS_List_Product_By_Date.ID;
    GV.DataBind();
    
}
```

**aspx**

```
<div id="DV_Datatable">
    <div class="form-group form-inline">
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="LA_Date" CssClass="LA_Date" Text="Date"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" ID="DD_List_Date_Select" CssClass="form-control" Width="150" DataSourceID="DS_List_Date" DataValueField="Date" DataTextField="Date" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DD_List_Date_Select_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GV" DataSourceID="DS_List_Date_Product" runat="server" CssClass="display table table-hover" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="text-info text-uppercase" />
    
        <Columns>
        
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Qty" DataField="Qty" SortExpression="Qty" />

        
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date" DataField="Date" SortExpression="Date"/>

        </Columns>
    
    </asp:GridView>

    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_List_Date" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cn %>" SelectCommand="DB_Liste_Date" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_List_Date_Product" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cn %>" SelectCommand="DB_List_Date_Product" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="DS_List_Product_By_Date" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:cn %>" SelectCommand="DB_List_Product_By_Date" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="DD_List_Date_Select" Name="Date" PropertyName="SelectedValue"/>
        </SelectParameters>
```

</asp:SqlDataSource>

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('<%= "#" + GV.ClientID %>').DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            "info": false,
            "language": {
                    "search": "Recherche :",
                    "infoFiltered": "",
                    "zeroRecords": "Pas de résultats pour cette recherche",
            }
        })
    })

</script>
```

To be clearer, if nobody can resolve this issue with datatable. I just want to create a dropdownlist and when I select a value in this list it update the view of my grid and I want to use datatable for my gridview.

**UPDATE**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'mData' of undefined
at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:90)
at Function.each (jquery.js:374)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js:139)
at HTMLTableElement.<anonymous> (jquery.dataTables.min.js:90)
at Function.each (jquery.js:374)
at n.fn.init.each (jquery.js:139)
at n.fn.init.m [as dataTable] (jquery.dataTables.min.js:82)
at n.fn.init.h.fn.DataTable (jquery.dataTables.min.js:167)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (aw_resiliation.aspx:733)
at j
```

Comment: Is it working when you load the page first time? Also, will you post full exception? Looks like you are not even using the sql datasource anywhere

Comment: try having a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201777/sqldatasource-binds-data-twice

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot no it doesn't work when i load my page for the first time

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I update my code now when I load the page for the first time I don't have the error with the modification.
But when I want to select a date I have the same error. I think it's because there is an `autopostback="true"` in the dropdownlist but if I turn it to false the code doesn't work.